# Count Distinct Paycheck with a Specific value

Tags: sql, select, count

I have this table  `MyTable` :

```
 Amount       Desc  Month Sym code  ID
 ------------------------------------------
 $32,323.00   Bla1    1   121 3   2424221
  $4,242.00   Bla1    1   121 3   2424221
 $32,323.00   Bla2    2   124 3   2424221
  $4,242.00   Bla2    2   124 3   2424221
 $32,323.00   Bla2    3   124 3   2424221
  $4,242.00   Bla3    1   126 3   2424221
  $3,535.00   Bla3    2   126 1   3230824
  $4,984.00   Bla4    1   433 1   3230824
 $47,984.00   Bla4    2   433 1   3230824
     $41.00   Bla4    2   433 1   3230824
  $3,472.00   Bla5    1   D2  27  2297429
  $3,472.00   Bla5    1   D2  27  2297429
  $3,239.00   Bla5    2   D2  27  2297429
  $3,472.00   Bla6    1   A2  27  2297429
  $3,239.00   Bla6    1   A2  27  2297429
  $3,239.00   Bla6    6   A2  27  3332321
  $3,239.00   Bla6    6   A2  27  3332321
  $4,249.00   Bla8    1   114 24  3434334
  $4,249.00   Bla8    2   114 24  3434334
  $4,249.00   Bla8    7   114 24  3434334
  $4,249.00   Bla8    7   114 24  3434334
```

How can I count how many months 121 a sym is showing up for employee? (At least one time.. meaning - if it 7 times in jan - one time, 8 times in feb - one time etc)

Comment: What dbms are you using?

Comment: Also provide desired results.

Comment: SQL Managment studio.

Example :

Comment: SQL Management studio isn't dbms. DBMS (*MySQL, SQL-Server, Oracle etc...*). So I think that *SQL-Server*.

Comment: ID 2424221
sym 121
GenralCount 2
UniqueCount 1

Becasue sym showed up twice but only one time in Jan and non in the other months.

Answer (score 0):

You can first `GROUP BY` Month and Sym, and then count the number of lines:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS NumberMonths121, SUM(Amount) SumAmount121 FROM (
  SELECT Month, Sym, COUNT(*) AS Amount
  FROM MyTable
  WHERE Sym=121
  GROUP BY Month,Sym
) AS subquery;
```

Comment: Thank's!
If I want to add sum of the amount (for all 121 for example) ?